# Google Map doesn't work on OpenShift

Tags: google-maps, openshift

I'm using Google Map API to on my website. When I run my web on local host, Google Map work well but when I deploy my web on OpenShift, Google Map doesn't work? I use java web with Tomcat

My index

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
    <meta name="author" content="lolkittens" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script src="GoogleMapAPI.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <title>Untitled 2</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

My js file:

```
function initialize() 
{
    var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(10.771400, 106.685844);
    var mapProp = 
    {
        center:myCenter,
        zoom:17,
        mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
    var marker=new google.maps.Marker(
    {
      position:myCenter,
      animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
    });

    marker.setMap(map);
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
    {
      content:"NHP Shop <br/> 274/9 Võ Văn Tần P5, Q3"
    });
    //add sự kiện onclick vào google map marker
    /*google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() 
    {
      infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });*/
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

So please tell me what wrong with my code? Thanks so much

Comment: Did you try adding API key ?

Comment: What are you seeing in Chrome Dev tools for JavaScript errors? (open up the rhcloud.com website in chrome, right click in screen then select `inspect`. )  Look for errors (red circle X) in the dev tools screens.  What do you see there?

Comment: Thank you all. I forgot the API key.